# Inserting information with checkboxes

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Here's the problem:

The user will input his information on the required fields. Then the user will choose a selection in check boxes (the user can choose multiple) which will be saved in database (the value of the check box).

For example:

David selected 2 choices. Sports for example. David choose Basketball and Volleyball.
In my database, it would look like this:

```
| id |  firstname  |  lastname  |  sports      |
| 1  | David       |  White     |  Basketball  |
| 2  | David       |  White     | Volleyball   |
```

My main problem is if I have to alter or delete the information, only one row will be altered or deleted which is a big problem. I can't make it like in explode or implode cause I have display the count of how many user have chosen a certain sport.

How am I able to solve this problem?

Comment: Here's a pretty good guide for Database Normalisation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (UPDATE: It seems like the english page isn't as good as the german one... But it'll give you a direction)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to normalize your table. You can create a table to store the person data:

```
 person = (personid, firstname, lastname, other fields related to person)
```

and a table to store the choices:

```
 sport = (sportid, name, other data related to sport)
```

And finally a table to manage the relationship:

```
 PersonSport = (personid, sportid)
```

Then in the above scenario your data will be:

```
 Person
 personid    Firstname    Lastname
  1          David        White
  2          Sam          Black
```

and

```
Sport
sportid       name
1             Basketball
2             Football
3             Tiddlywinks
```

and

```
 PersonSport
 Personid   Sportid
   1        1
   1        2
   2        3
   2        1
```

To count how many users selected a sport:

```
  Select count(*) from PersonSport where sportid = 1;
```

Comment: can you show me the SQL statment needed when I will delete the whole information of David? And the Personid is not incremented is it?

Comment: Person has a n:m-relation to Sports, so I would create three tables: Person, Sports, and a transformed table (e.g. PersonSports).

Comment: Thats right @FabioPoloni . Assuming that there is more data to be stored about the sports, then the table I listed called Sports should be PersonSport which will contain the primary keys of Sport and Person.